# No Branch Type within Jira's "Create Branch" from Issue

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I'm currently using an integrated setup of Sourcetree, Jira, and Bitbucket and they all seem to be communicating fine. My current workflow process has my team creating issues within Jira and then using the "create branch" feature within the created issue to introduce a new branch into BitBucket. My problem is, I've seen other examples where you have the option to pick what branch type you would like the branch to be (feature, hotfix, etc) from a simple drop down menu. However, I don't seem to have that option available in my Create Branch menu and I'm hoping if I could enable it, it would allow me to better utilize the default GitFlow tab and simplify the process for my team. Is this an add on I can't find or enabled from somewhere I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're looking for is not available in the Cloud version of Bitbucket.

You might have seen this option [in their docs](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branches-in-bitbucket-server-776639968.html?_ga=2.194557997.1417293772.1520408848-568888109.1509965142#UsingbranchesinBitbucketServer-settings), but this is related to Bitbucket's Server version, which you have to host yourself, on your own server.

If you don't intend to host Bitbucket, you'll have to wait for the [already available feature request](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12833/branching-models-do-bb-cloud?_ga=2.232971422.1417293772.1520408848-568888109.1509965142) implementation.

Just keep in mind that Atlassian tends to take a long time to act on those type of requests and often deciding not to do them after years of discussion, as they already said, 2 days ago, that [addressing this feature is not part of their plans right now](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12833/branching-models-do-bb-cloud?_ga=2.232971422.1417293772.1520408848-568888109.1509965142#comment-43757187).

Cheers!